# Xpath or Xquery ignoring any type of namespace prefix

Tags: java, xpath, soap, xquery

I have SOAP response from where I’m retrieving part of it and thats part looks like

```
<ns4:discounts>
      <ns4:discount code=‘ABC’ description=‘Hello World’ /> </ns4:discounts>
```

But what I need is following(e.g. wihout namespace prefix)

```
<discounts>
      <discount code=‘ABC’ description=‘Hello World’ />
</discounts>
```

How can I get this using xquery or xpath? As I already mentioned I’m getting discounts part from SOAP reponse(which is not included here)

Please help, thanks.

Comment: What technology are you using to transform this XML? Basically you will have to re-create the elements.

Comment: I’m using Xquery with //*[local-name

Comment: And what XQuery processor are you using?

Comment: I’m using xquery inside of Apache Camel so it would be better that you can suggest a way to get  without ns prefix or include namespace declaration from soap header to response which Im getting in ouput

Answer (score 0):

If the input nodes are in a namespace then any query that simply selects nodes from the input is going to return nodes that are in a namespace. If you want nodes in no namespace then you will need to transform the input rather than simply selecting from it, which you can do in XQuery but not in XPath. (And you can do it much more easily in XSLT.) Essentially you have to reconstruct the XML by a recursive traversal of the tree, where the new nodes are formed by renaming the old nodes.

Comment: Can you suggest way to get this output included namespace declaration. I mean to get ouput like <ns4:discounts and here namespace declaration which is described in Soap header that Im getting. Thanks

Comment: I don't understand your supplementary question, sorry. Has your requirement changed? Too busy to write code for you today anyway.